# How to share React-Redux store across different applications?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am building an application that is basically two different react apps being served on different paths (/remote and /screen) that need to share the same state. /remote is a mobile view that controls what is displayed on another client view at /screen.

Currently have it setup as one React app rendering different views based on react-router path. I'm wrapping react-router in , a-la react-redux.

Problem is the state changes from one client arent being reflected in the other but I'm not sure exactly why.

My question is, can this be done with the described architecture or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: you need a server or something like firebase to share data between clients

Comment: why don't you just use react-redux connect ?